# Incorrect encoding in downloaded installer shell script

Tags: software-installation

[image]

I am trying to install installer files with the extension sh.

Comment: What installer?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine the miniconda linux installer https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Answer (score 0):

Why did you open the script in `mousepad`? AFAIK, `mousepad` is a text editor. To install the script do the following.

Step 1: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to open `terminal`

Step 2: Find the directory in which you have downloaded the installer(probably Downloads)

Step 3: Enter that directory using

```
cd Downloads
```

Step 4: Run the command. This command fill find the scripts present in the directory

```
ls -l | grep .sh
```

Step 6: Give the script executable permission using

```
chmod +x <filename>
```

replace  with the installer file name

Step 7: Finally run the script using

```
./<installer>
```

replace  with the installer file name

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you did but I think the installation process is quite clear in their documentations and the means of installing is the terminal and not any file explorer. Please open a terminal with the keyboard combinations of "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>  in the installer's location and run these commands or **right click and select the context menu option "open in Terminal"** and run those commands:

In your terminal window, run:

- Miniconda:

  ```
  bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
  ```
- Anaconda:

  ```
  bash Anaconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
  ```

[image]

Installation gif:

[image]

Source:

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html